# Emoji in Keynote

Tags: keynote, emoji

I cannot insert emojis in a keynote presentation. More precisely, when I insert one (Edit > Special characters), I have a blank space instead of the emoji.

This works very fine with textedit.

Does anyone successfully did that?

(Lion 10.7.1 and Keynote'09 5.1)

Comment: There is a very friendly workaround. Check out my answer here https://superuser.com/a/1198362/414191

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think iWork has not yet been updated to support the Apple Color Emoji font.

The vast majority of the special characters that are monochrome work fine - you might try the old way of specifying a font directly - [**Symbola**](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) has emoticons that might work until Keynote gets updated.

Comment: I don't really understand what needs to be updated though.

Comment: The Apple Color Emoji font is special in certain ways.  I don't think it will work in 10.6 or in apps not programmed to accept it (but I have not tried very many with it yet).

Comment: I understand that the font is extremely different from the usual concept of fonts (it uses different colors to render a single glyph), but the system should be responsible for the rendering of fonts, not a program…

Comment: @loick  I think different apps may use different parts of the "system" for various things.  The inferior behavior of Pages (for years now) compared to TextEdit for certain font related issues is well known to people who need to use Arabic, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Emoticons and other symbols work for me as only when I am typing inside a text box.
I tried dragging them to keynote but nothing happened.
But when I 'called' them using the Edit... menu that you found they were inserted in my text.
I was able to resize, move...